# How to do a loop with intellij http_client?

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like to execute several http requests (in one http file) with intellij http client in a loop based on an array of strings in an environment file. Is this possible? If  yes, how?
Thx,
Alex

Comment: Please follow the related request on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-320379